# Unload js file reference from modal dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using bootstrap modal in my project and using following lines of code I have opened modal popup window.

```
$('#divLookupModel').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    show: true,
    height: dHeight,
    cache: false
}).find('.modal-body').load(strUrl);
```

The issue is that when I opened modal popup on button click load some .js file reference and on close I have cleared the content using below code.

```
$("#divLookupModel .modal-body").empty();
```

After that when I again open the pop up from different button click the previously loaded .js file reference remains as it is.So please tell me how can I remove the previously loaded .js file reference on close of modal dialog?

Answer (score 0):

> $('#divLookupModel').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
>       $(this).find('form').trigger('reset');
>   })

try above instead of $("#divLookupModel .modal-body").empty();